# Coordinate Bond...(Dative Bond)

Tags: coordination-compounds

Is NH4Cl Dative or Ionic or Covalent ?
I made the Lewis structure but I was not able to make it...
After many tries I posted this question
Some where I saw that they are made up of Ions but contain Covalent bond..

Comment: It is all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

The bonding between $\ce{NH4+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ is ionic.

The bonding between $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{H+}$ in $\ce{NH4+}$ is a dative bond. (Since $\ce{H+}$ ion has no electrons, 2 electrons from $\ce{N}$ atom in $\ce{NH3}$ form the coordinate bond with $\ce{H+}$, thus forming $\ce{NH4+}$)

The bonding between $\ce{N}$ atom and $\ce{H}$ atom in $\ce{NH3}$ is covalent.